# is it normal that i didn't encounter any thing related to the mokutil during the process of installing nvidia driver on ubuntu 22.10 with secureboot?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, secure-boot

i installed ubuntu 22.10 with secure boot and nvidia drivers.

I know about the dkms bug

steps to reproduce

1-during installation i didn't install third party drivers

2-i updated the system then restart

3-i enabled the proposed repo and installed the updated "dkms" package (sudo apt install dkms)

4- disabled proposed repo and reboot

5-I installed the nvidia driver with gui (proprietary  ,tested) and rebooted the system successfully and ubuntu.
the nvidia driver is working

**the problem** is i didn't encounter mokutil during and after the  installation of nvidia driver . (like creating password then after the reboot i enroll mok)

Comment: ubuntu 22.10 release notes indicated that there is a bug in dkms make the process of signing fails .

Comment: ubuntu 22.10 release notes indicated that there is a bug in dkms make the process of signing fails .     and the  problem is that almost all resources show that there is a third step of installing dkms kernel module when you are using secureboot which is create a password then when the system restarted you will see a blue screen ask you to enroll mok i was dealing with this process when installing wifi that doesn't have opensource drives inside the kernel .so when installing nvidia drivers whick it is a dkms module and not facing the mokutil that means that there is some thing wrong

Comment: thanks for explanation @Nmath